# Where do we mention the gitlab-runner executor in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab

I have a very simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
```

And run this pipeline. It uses a shared gitlab runner.

The job executed in a docker container. But we haven't mentioned  `docker executor` for `gitlab runner` and also any image. So how is this whole thing done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Running your CI/CD jobs in Docker containers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) implies to Register a runner so that all jobs run in Docker containers.

But if you are [using GitLab SaaS (GitLab.com)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/), your CI jobs automatically run on runners in the GitLab Build Cloud.

With a [Linux runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/build_cloud/linux_build_cloud.html), that means [n1-standard-1 instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) with 3.75GB of RAM, CoreOS and the latest Docker Engine installed.

Comment: I am `using GitLab SaaS (GitLab.com)`. You say `your CI jobs automatically run on runners in the GitLab Build Cloud With a Linux runner`. So `Linux Runner` is like a droplet (in digital ocean) or AWS EC2 instance (for my imagination). So gitlab runners are like Virutal PCS.

Comment: @Santhosh By default, yes.

Comment: So within that virtual PC (the Linux runner) - creates a docker container and then inside that runs the script.

Comment: @Santhosh Yes, by default a ruby:2.5 docker image, able to execute shell commands.